# Нерешаемый вопрос

Tags: причастия

Недавно мне пришел ответ от ИРЯ РАН, в котором говорилось, что проблема разграничения причастия/прилагательного нерешаема (в определенных случаях), поскольку по этому вопросу нет у лингвистов единого мнения.

---

Возьму банальный пример:
**"успокаивающая улыбка"**.
Относительно значения этого слова имеем следующее: МАС считает это прич. в значении прилагательного, Ефремова считает только прилагательным.

---

***Почему в данных словарях представлены столь категоричные утверждения, если проблема неразрешима?***

Comment: Может, поэтому в БТС у многих слов нет информации о части речи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Попробуем разобраться **с примером.**

*"Возьму банальный пример: "успокаивающая улыбка". Относительно значения этого слова имеем следующее: МАС считает это прич. в значении прилагательного, Ефремова считает только прилагательным".*

МАС — последнее издание в 1981—1984 годах[, Ефремова — 2015 год.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Малый_академический_словарь
https://dic.academic.ru/book.nsf/62313041/Современный+тол

Лингвисты работали в разное время  и делали **однозначный вывод** в соответствии с приоритетной терминологией. Нужно ориентироваться **на Ефремову,** это более современный вариант. Я могу предположить, что в настоящий момент термин  «причастие в значении прилагательного» в учебном процессе не применяется.

2. Возможно, среди лингвистов и сейчас **нет полного взаимопонимания**, но  в словарях и учебниках они должны применять одинаковые  основные термины  в соответствии с общепринятым  (наиболее авторитетным) среди них мнением.
3. Поэтому ответ ИРЯ РАН (применительно к приведенному примеру) не кажется убедительным: в этом случае **нет причин** для невозможности решения. Просто  в учебниках и словарях надо пользоваться **единой терминологией**, что и делается по возможности (как **у Ефремовой**).

Comment: Ни в коем случае не надо ориентироваться на нее. У нее полнейшая путаница в понятиях. В школе, например, точно не на нее опираются.  Лучше всего подойдет Лопатин (2008 г.). Его разъяснение снимает абсолютное большинство вопросов, жаль, что там не о всех причастиях есть информация.

Comment: Вы используете два термина: прилагательное и в значении прилагательного? Какая между ними разница? А что за Лопатин (2008), как называется источник? И почему наш автор вопроса сравнивает МАС и Ефремову? А не Лопатина?  Я ведь отвечала на вопрос, что выбрать из этих двух. А Лопатин какой термин использует?

Comment: В школе четко: прилагательное или причастие. У Лопатина так же.

Comment: Орфографический словарь русского языка. 2006.

Comment: А словарь РАН на Грамоте.ру чем от него отличается? Он вроде бы ежегодно редактируется. И как сравнивать орфографический и толковый словари? В школе четко: прилагательное или причастие?  Так и Ефремовой то же самое, в отличие от МАС. Какие к ней вопросы? Ее толковый словарь самый полный, все им пользуются.

Comment: Это не один и тот же словарь. Множество слов интерпретировано по-разному.

Comment: Словарь Ефремовой неинформативен. К тому же он не соответствует грамматике школы.

Comment: А зачем вам сравнивать орфографический и толковый словари? Мы же о грамматике говорим: причастие или прилагательное. Для грамматики один авторитет - орфографический словарь.

Comment: Они тогда во всем авторитет,  последнее слово  в том, как и что надо.  Я считала, что Ми Моли сравнивает толковые словари Ефремовой и МАС, там тоже есть сведения по грамматике. Грамматика сама по себе авторитет в своей области, а РАН использует полученные сведения и оформляет их. Так мне думается.

Comment: Толковый словарь Ефремовой https://dic.academic.ru/book.nsf/62313041/Современный+тол  Чем же он неинформативен?  Грамматику уточняйте в других источниках. А школьная грамматика – это грамматика для школы, упрощенный вариант.  Литневскую читайте на Грамоте.ру или  используйте другие источники, ориентированные на школу.

Comment: Я не думаю, что автору интересно, как там считают ученые. Даже если так, то найдется множество противоречивых точек зрения. Вопрос наверняка о школьных принципах. В школе все четко: причастие или прилагательное. У Ефремовой все в куче, там нет логики разграничения, нет примеров. Логика есть у МАС, но она тоже неидеальна, поскольку авторы включают спорные примеры в группу прилагательных, а составители экз.материалов апеллируют только к бесспорным случаям, поэтому, если опираться на логику Ефремовой и даже МАС, может выйти так, что "фаршированный", "маринованный" уйдут в прилагательные..

Comment: Что никак не соотносится с общепринятой школьной практикой: там эти слова причастия, как и у Лопатина (2008 г.), поэтому стоит обращаться только к этому словарю и не обращать внимания на другие источники.

Comment: Используйте словари и другие источники по назначению. По толковым словарям смотрите значения слов, а грамматику уточняйте в словаре РАН.  Нравится Лопатин?  Работайте по нему., но не надо в толковых словарях искать сведения для школьной грамматики.

Comment: Вы меня не услышали. Автора интересует вопрос разграничения причастий и прилагательных. Ответ: нужно смотреть не эти словари, которые перечислены выше, а Орфографический словарь русского языка 2006 года. Там будет указано, когда слово является прилагательным (если оно может быть им), а когда причастием. Единственная проблема этого справочника в том, что он не включает в себя информацию о тех словах, частеречная принадлежность которых не важна для правописания: ДПНВ, СПНВ и некоторые ДППВ.

Comment: Я вас услышала, а вот вы не поняли заданного вопроса. Почитайте его внимательно, там никто на выбирает между причастием и прилагательным, там с термином для прилагательных разбираются. Вот мы и говорим на разных языках. В любом случае спасибо за беседу.