# Чем отличаются слова "нерешаемый" и "неразрешимый"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, семантика

Эти слова **нормированы** в русском языке и сходны по значению, но насколько  они **взаимозаменяемы?**

Каково **значение** каждого слова и в каких **ситуациях** их надо применять? Желательно привести примеры.

Спасибо.

P.S. Тема связана  [с недавним вопросом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474743/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81), где были использованы **оба слова**, что показалось мне **интересным**.  Кстати, эту ситуацию можно взять в качестве **примера** для этой темы, а может, и для ответа на **тот** вопрос.

Comment: Ссылка на улыбку, а не на вопрос про нерешаемый/неразрешаемый. Нерешаемый - больше про способ решения, то есть вообще есть ли способ решения, то есть когда есть некий вопрос в задаче, цель, но как её достичь не ясно. Неразрешимый предполагает, что даже самого вопроса нет, так как любой поставленный вопрос выглядит некорректно с учетом условия, постановка проблемы уже содержит опровержение цели решения. Нерешаемый - это указание на сложность, связанную с методом решения или временем, может о том, что в данном конкретном случае это не решаемо. А неразрешимый - вообще то, что не решается никогда.

Comment: нерешаемый - ставит вопрос к тому кто решает, его методу, способу, а неразрешимый к условию или к постановке проблемы в целом. неразрешимый более сильная форма, нерешаемый - потому что, неразрешимый - без всяких потому что.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ (жаль, что не в поле ответа). Вроде бы похоже на правду, но слишком уж отвлеченно и отстраненно от конкретной практики того вопроса и той ситуации.  Подождем (хотя бы до завтра) другие ответы, а потом я выскажу свое мнение  по этой теме в целом.

Comment: Тоже зацепился там за эти слова :)

Comment: Надо анализировать "решить" и "разрешить".

Comment: По ходу, зависит от объекта. При "неразрешимый" объект глобальнее. *Проблема нерешаема. Неразрешимая проблема человечества.* Во втором вроде бы "нерешаемая" не очень.

Comment: Слова действительно" цепляют", но, кажется, не всех...) В обоих словах звучит кая-то обреченность в той или иной степени.

Comment: Ну да. Меня зацепило на минуту. Здесь разница маленькая из-за того, что тот же корень. Как вам моё отличие? Согласны? Или во втором у вас "нерешаемая" звучит не хуже.

Comment: Я эти слова совсем не использую и стараюсь не замечать)) Подальше ото всех нерешаемых и неразрешимых проблема человечества. Не наше это дело, пусть верхние миры думают. (Человек принадлежит человечеству, поэтому разуметь о себе ничего не может, хотя и очень хочет.) Что касается ЛЕКСИКИ, то там все условно, и нам остается понимать эту условность в пределах заданной задачи, а не в общем случае. Кстати, мне показалась примечательной именно ЗАМЕНА слов, переход к усилению.

Comment: Предложение в скобках трудно понять. Люди людей изучают. Другое дело, что сложно изучать то, чем изучают. Но это уже другая история. Так что, как вам моё отличие? "Неразрешимый" явно пафоснее (глобальнее), даже на слух. То, о чём говорит Буратино, улавливаю (надо было проще и чётче сформулировать, мало кто поймёт), но нельзя сказать, что с "неразрешимый" прямо всегда так.

Comment: Ну да, усиление — ещё одно отличие. Довольно очевидная вещь.

Comment: А я и не знаю, что думать... Поэтому объясните замену слов применительно  к решению проблемы причастие/прилагательное. Нерешаемая это проблема или неразрешимая. Правильно использованы там слова в обоих случаях? Вы так же написали бы? Или надо было лингвистам  по-другому ответить, чтобы объяснить расхождение? Удобная такая позиция – нерешаемый вопрос! А кто мешает его решить-таки?

Comment: я считаю, что раз - это тоже корень, а не приставка.

Comment: Честно говоря, меня это даже немного напрягло. Вроде бы оба слова подходят (средняя глобальность). Скорее всего, соблюдал бы последовательность. Всё-таки это не то же самое. И раз тот же объект, то лучше использовать то же определение (выбор зависит от объекта, как сказано выше). Касательно решения: как-то уже объяснял Jim Korbett это, сейчас сложно найти, в общем, они действуют поодиночке, они не съезжаются с далёких уголков на съезды, чтобы договориться. И не факт, что отвечал лингвист. Лингвистами считают написавших лингвистические труды (работы для получения учёной степени не в счёт).

Comment: Нерешаемая задача, неразрешимое дело. То что задачу решили на бумаге, не гарантирует, что это вообще можно сделать, то есть разрешить каким-то образом. Решение - это теория, а раз - это связь с практической реализацией и действием.

Comment: Решить спор - найти компромиссное решение удовлетворяющее все стороны. Разрешить спор - устранить причину спора, сделать так, чтобы спор стал бессмысленным. Раз - это указание на причину, а обычные глаголы - это предикаты будущего, решить спор - решенный спор. Разрешенный спор - не скажешь, это уже какие-то правила, разрешенное. То есть предикат - он всегда про будущее, а не про то что есть.

Answer (score 1):

**1. По  грамматике**  глаголы ***решить*** (сов.) и ***решать*** (несов.)  образуют видовую пару, но есть  еще глагол ***разрешить*** (сов.). Приставка ***РАЗ*** в его составе используется для образования совершенного вида, но при этом придает глаголу **дополнительное значение** всестороннего охвата проблемы и полноты действия (подходящий смысл можно уточнить по словарю для этой приставки).

От глагола ***решать*** образуются причастия ***решаемый/нерешаемый***, а от глагола ***разрешить*** — прилагательные ***разрешимый/неразрешимый***.
Например: Разрешимый конфликт— это конфликт, который в конечном итоге решится. Сам собой или герою придется приложить для этого усилия. Неразрешимый конфликт— тот который никогда  не решится в силу объективных причин.

2. @Ми Моли использует в тексте вопроса оба слова, то есть они вроде бы  синонимы, но насколько это правомерно.

Итак, два источника (МАС и Ефремова) предлагают нам разное решение  для разграничения причастия/прилагательного, а ИРЯ РАН говорит, что «проблема различения прилагательных/причастий  в некоторых случаях **нерешаема**, та как у лингвистов нет единого мнения».

А дальше в тексте делается  замена слов:  «Почему в данных словарях представлены столь категоричные утверждения, если проблема **неразрешима**?»

3. Как же разобраться с этой "решаемостью" именно **в данной ситуации?** Вроде бы проблема может решиться, если лингвисты найдут это единое мнение. Тогда разграничение причастий/прилагательных состоится, а пока сложный вопрос обозначен как ***нерешаемый.*** Подождать надо!

А чего ждать-то — может, они никогда не придут  к общему мнению?   Скорее всего, так и есть. Поэтому мы полны пессимизма и называем  проблему ***неразрешимой***.

Так можно объяснить наличие двух вариантов слов (нерешаемый и неразрешимый)  в одном тексте. Происходит как бы **усиление** смысла сказанного.

4. Но тогда надо **найти это общее мнение** (сделать выбор), и  все встанет на свои места. Итак, есть два термина: (1) прич. в значении прилагательного, (2) только прилагательное.  Если бы термин был один, то не было бы вопросов.

**Разная терминология** для одного явления — вот в чем причина разногласия мнений. Для учебных целей это весьма **нежелательно**, поэтому делаем **выбор в пользу Ефремовой**, так как это более современная терминология. МАС — последнее издание в 1981—1984 годах[, Ефремова — 2015 год.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Малый_академический_словарь
https://www.livelib.ru/author/81395/latest-tatyana-efremova

Итак, в современной учебной практике и в словарях **не следует использовать** термин «прич. в значении прилагательного», даже если он возможен в лингвистике.

5. **И общий вывод**: причиной разных точек зрения  может быть неоднозначность исходных **определений**, тогда стороны никогда **не найдут общего решения**, так что и спорить не имеет смысла. Задача будет **нерешаемой** при таких условиях. Если же согласие в определениях не может быть найдено никогда, то задача становится **неразрешимой.**

Comment: И без приставки совершенный вид, так что нет, утверждение не верно. С приставкой возможен и несовершенный: *разрешать*.

Comment: Решимый/нерешимый? Вы используете эти слова? В Нацкорпусе только один пример 1839 года "нерешимый вопрос". А слова "решимый" совсем нет.

Comment: Разрешаемый вопрос – возможная форма, но опять же частотность какая? В нацкорпусе один пример 1889 года "вопрос, разрешаемый ежедневно". В этом слове нет потребности, естественный отбор.

Comment: Мне и те не приходилось использовать.

Comment: РАЗРЕШИТЬ 2. что или с придат. дополнит. Исследуя, обдумывая что-л., решить, найти правильный ответ. Р. трудный вопрос. Р. какую-л. проблему, задачу, загадку. Трудно р., которое из дел важнее. Р. сомнительные случаи правописания. РЕШИТЬ - После обдумывания прийти к какому-л. выводу, к необходимости каких-л. действий. Р. учиться. Р. посвятить себя искусству. Р. вопрос с отъездом. Внезапно р. уехать. Р. изучать русский язык. Решил, что спешить некуда. Попробуй реши, как поступить в этом случае

Comment: Т.е. разрешить имеет дополнительное значение: исследовать, долго обдумывать, что найти верный ответ. А "решить"  -прийти к заключению  после обдумывания.

Comment: @Серж Это следствие того, что разрешают более сложное.