# Обстоятельство или дополнение

Tags: сложное-предложение

Он сел отдельно **от всех**.

Сел (как) отдельно, отдельно (от кого) от всех

**или**

Сел (как) отдельно от всех

Comment: А контекст есть? И по какой программе занятия, там проходят несвободные сочетания?

Comment: @Sharon отдельно написанное предложение.

Comment: А программа какая (о несвободных сочетаниях)?

Comment: @Sharon Школьная.

Comment: Они проходят несвободные сочетания?

Comment: По идее да, проходят.

Comment: Возможно, вопрос связан с сочетаниями.  Наречие может управлять сущ., но сочетание может быть контекстуально несвободным.  Вот это надо решать, а без контеста трудно определиться.

Comment: @Sharon А вы как думаете?

Comment: Я сейчас напишу в поле ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что это **обстоятельство** целиком. Трудность определения роли предложно-падежного сочетания заключается в том, что непонятна частеречная принадлежность слова "отдельно". Может ли оно находиться в предложении самостоятельно и иметь полноценное значение - может (как ***наречие***), но не в этом предложении. В этом предложении оно является частью предложно-падежного сочетания ***"отдельно от всех"***. Это сочетание почему-то не зафиксировано в словаре, но то, что оно является предлогом, можно понять путем сопоставления с другим сочетанием, противоположным по значению.

---

**Сравните**:

1)Он сел ***отдельно от*** всех.

2)Он сел ***вместе со*** всеми.

---

Разделять ни в коем случае нельзя. Это **грубейшая ошибка**. Предложно-падежное сочетание является одним членом предложения. Напомню, что **у наречия нет и не может быть зависимых слов**, за исключением других наречий меры и степени. Если у наречий появляются зависимыми словами, они становятся предлогами и вступают в тесные синтаксические отношения с другими словами, становясь неделимыми.

ТО, что слова нет в словаре, ни о чем не говорит: невозможно записать все сочетания, которые возникнут при соединении наречия с другим словом.

**Сравнить:**

У слова **"близко"** в словаре нет ни одной пометы, говорящей о том, что оно может являться предлогом.
Однако достаточно посмотреть Викисловарь, чтобы обнаружить там следующее:

> бли́зко от. Устойчивое сочетание (предлог). Используется в качестве наречной группы. Требует родительный падеж.

---

P.S. Некоторые **псевдоэксперты** думают, что в словарях отражены все возможные варианты употребления той или иной части речи в языке, при этом они даже не понимают основ языкового строя и ссылаются на **непонятные** сайты.

---

Порой для них даже трудно открыть словарь:

> вме́сте с предл. с твор.; = вме́сте со

Comment: К сожалению, вы не указываете, в каком словаре.  У Ефремовой толковый словарь, там могут быть грамматические неточности. Но в орфографическом словаре РАН предлога ВМЕСТЕ С нет.  В то же время другие предлоги  там обозначены.

Answer (score 1):

Если контекста нет, то будем считать словосочетание **свободным**.

В словаре:

**ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ**, Отдельно, нареч. (1 зн.). Дети шли о., без взрослых. Изба стоит о. от других. Жить о. от родителей.

Наречие может использоваться без  распространителя или с любым распространителем, поэтому я выберу первый вариант: *Сел (как) **отдельно**, отдельно (от кого) **от всех**.*

**[Наречные словосочетания](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/narechnye-slovosochetaniia.html)**

Наречие в составе такого словосочетания является **главным словом**. Оно может **управлять существительным,** требуя от него определенного падежа, и тогда между словами этих частей речи осуществляется подчинительная **связь управления**: (выглядит) грустно (до чего?) до слёз.

Примеры: близко от леса; далеко от дома; направо от парка.

**Толковый словарь Ефремовой:** отдельно нареч. обстоят. качества

1. Не будучи частью чего-либо целого, единого.
2. перен. Изолированно.

**Пример оформления в словаре предлогов и парных наречий и наречных предлогов:**

**ПРИМЕНИТЕЛЬНО,** **предлог**. к кому-чему. 1. В зависимости от чего-л. Действовать применительно к обстановке. 2. По отношению к кому-, чему-л. Применительно к современным исследованиям необходимо учитывать качество оборудования. Применительно к этому человеку ваши упрёки несправедливы.

**ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНО.** **I. нареч.** В известной мере, до некоторой степени; сравнительно. Прыжок о. высокий. Море было о. спокойно. Конец повести о. благополучный. **II. предлог.** кого-чего. По отношению к кому-, чему-л., в отношении кого-, чего-л. Симметрия геометрических фигур о. оси. Исполнить свой долг о. наследников. Не иметь определённых намерений о. кого-л.

**ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ РАН (указано управление для НАРЕЧИЯ, им можно верить,особенно в школе)**

**вместе**, нареч. (**с кем-, чем-н.**, не в одиночку)

**Примечание.** В словаре указаны **падежные вопросы** для обозначения **НОРМЫ** управления (Т.п., предлог С).  К примеру, нормы  управления указаны для переходных глаголов с сильным управлением: ПОНЯТЬ, св. ***кого-что.*** В современной лингвистике требование определенного падежа **не является** фактором, определяющим переход наречия в предлог.

**ВЫВОД.** Предлог  ***ОТДЕЛЬНО ОТ*** не обозначен **в словаре**, поэтому нет оснований считать словосочетание предлогом. Также нет и предлога ***ВМЕСТЕ С***.

Comment: Будьте любезны, уберите ваши комментарии и пишите свои тексты в поле своего ответа. Не нарушайте правила. И кто с вами спорит и вообще разговаривает. Не вижу собеседников.

Comment: МИНУСОВКа ОППОНЕНТА - это все, на что вы способны.

Comment: когда пытаются доказать свою "правоту", но не могут, то минусуют. Я убрал минус.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж.  Я нашла интересную статью про наречное управление и наречные предлоги.  Дискуссионная тема в лингвистике. Но в словаре, как я думаю, наречные предлоги должны быть обозначены.

Comment: «_**ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ РАН (указано управление для НАРЕЧИЯ, им можно верить, особенно в школе)**_ === Нет, в РОС управления не даются.   
То, что помещено в скобках в статье **вместе**, лишь кратко раскрывает **ЗНАЧЕНИЕ** этого слова: **вместе** — это значит  **с кем-нибудь, с чем-нибудь, не в одиночку**.

Comment: Это все тонкости. Главное – в словаре РАН не указаны предлоги ВМЕСТЕ С и ОТДЕЛЬНО ОТ. А вот запись для предлога: ВСЛЕД ЗА (чем), предлог. Переход наречия в наречный предлог должен быть зафиксирован в словаре. Лингвисты и те спорят, обсуждая каждый переход, а анаш участник все знает: это грубейшая ошибка. Но в словаре написано, что это наречия. Так это предлоги или наречия? Запишите, пожалуйста,  свое мнение под ответом другого участника.

Answer (score 0):

Из комментария в мой адрес в этой теме:

> Но в словаре написано, что это наречия. Так это предлоги или наречия?
> Запишите, пожалуйста, свое мнение под ответом другого участника.

Выражу своё мнение здесь.

С ответом ‘другого участника’ (Ajgy) я практически полностью согласен.

Практически то же, что написал **Ajgy**, сказано и в справочнике [**Шелякин М.А. «Справочник по русской грамматике». М., 2000**]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что же до предлога ***вместе с***… Не знаю, почему его нет в «Русском орфографическом словаре». Скорее всего – просто упущение составителей словаря. Во всяком случае, в **Грамматике–80** в разделе «Предлоги», написанном Н.Ю. Шведовой, он есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень вы любить старые архивы, все ссылки  за прошлый век или  на частные мнения отдельных лингвистов, хотелось бы что-нибудь ПОНОВЕЕ и поактуальнее. И спасибо за двойную МИНУСОВКУ, участник Слава. Не забудьте  так пометить все мои ответы, если вы в этом видите важную составляющую вашей работы на форуме.  Ваш коллектив выходит на первое место в рейтинге. Так держать!  Желаю вам  и участнику Ajgy новых грамматических открытий.

Comment: «_**Очень вы любить старые архивы, все ссылки за прошлый век или на частные мнения отдельных лингвистов, хотелось бы что-нибудь ПОНОВЕЕ и поактуальнее. И спасибо за двойную МИНУСОВКУ, участник Слава. Не забудьте так пометить все мои ответы, если вы в этом видите важную составляющую вашей работы на форуме. Ваш коллектив выходит на первое место в рейтинге. Так держать!**_» === Во-первых, **Грамматику-80** люблю не только я: Вы тоже на неё ссылаетесь – и тогда не считаете её «старым архивом». А во-вторых, совсем ничего не понял о «**двойной минусовке**». Вы что, думаете, что это я минусовал ???

Comment: Не волнуйтесь, я запись не сотру, можете не копировать. А кто же еще меня минусует,  вы первый кандидат. Здесь же автографов нет.  Правда, есть и другие, но они тоже вряд ли "личико откроют".  За свой ответ я получила три минуса, но сама никого не минусую. А Грамматику-80 я тоже люблю, сейчас добавлю кое-что.  Но составных наречных предлогов из СПИСКА нет в словаре РАН, видно, тоже еще не внесли.

Comment: «_**А кто же еще меня минусует, вы первый кандидат. Здесь же автографов нет.**_» === Sharon, успокойтесь: не я (хотя, может, иногда и следовало бы ). В качестве подтверждения  могу предоставить Вам фото с странички моих «достижений» на этом форуме, которое подтвердит моё неучастие в минусовании чьих-либо ответов.

Comment: НЕ НАДО. В любом случае, я ПРИОСТАНАВЛИВАЮ свою работу. Получать по три минуса за каждый ответ у меня нет желания. В этом и ваша заслуга тоже. Лучше займусь систематизацией материалов с форума. Кстати, ценная вещь для практики письма, причем во всех отношениях.

Comment: Очень уместное дополнение, Слава. Спасибо за ваш ответ. Мой голос  - за вас!

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ в качестве комментария

**В качестве вступления** добавлю немного академичности. **Русская грамматика** под ред. Шведовой, 1990

**§ 410. Управление наречий**

Падежными и предложно-падежными формами имен существительных управляет **достаточно большой круг** обстоятельственных и качественно- обстоятельственных наречий, во многих случаях это управление обнаруживает признаки **сильной связи**: *вдали от дома, тайком от родителей, наперекор судьбе, согласно требованиям/с требованиями.*

У **качественных** наречий связь с формами существительных имеет необязательный характер: *обидно до слез, непонятно для слушателей.*

У **обстоятельственных** наречий управление легко формируется на синтаксической основе: *жить далеко за селом — далеко за селом, подняться задолго до рассвета — задолго до рассвета.*

1. Итак, правильный **ответ для школьной аудитории**  определяем голосованием: ***ОТДЕЛЬНО ОТ*** — предлог! Наречия не могут управлять существительными. Считать так — это грубейшая ошибка. (***ВМЕСТЕ С*** — тоже предлог.)

А это цитата из нового **"правила"** для школьников, запишите пожалуйста, дети:

*Если у наречий появляются **зависимыми словами**, они становятся предлогами и вступают в тесные синтаксические отношения с другими словами, становясь неделимыми.*

2. **А как же словарь РАН**, неужели стал неавторитетным? Вот совсем недавнее мнение **участника Ajgy** из темы [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474743/Нерешаемый-вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474743/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

*Словарь Ефремовой **неинформативен**. К тому же он не соответствует грамматике школы. Ни в коем случае не надо ориентироваться на нее (на Ефремову). У нее **полнейшая путаница в понятиях**. В школе, например, точно **не на нее опираются**. Словарь Ефремовой неинформативен. К тому же он **не соответствует грамматике школы.** А зачем вам сравнивать орфографический и толковый словари? Мы же о грамматике говорим: причастие или прилагательное. **Для грамматики один авторитет – орфографический словарь.** Ajgy 8 авг в 11:33*

3. Но почему же этих предлога **нет в словаре РАН?** Так ясное дело, ***упущение-с.*** Ох уж эти лингвисты, такие невнимательные. Но ничего, скоро исправятся. Вот что считают "новые исследователи":

*Это сочетание почему-то не зафиксировано в словаре, но то, что оно является предлогом, **можно понять путем сопоставления** с другим сочетанием, противоположным по значению Сравните: 1)Он сел отдельно от всех. 2) Он сел вместе со всеми (Ajgy).*

*С ответом ‘другого участника’ (Ajgy) я практически полностью согласен. Что же до предлога вместе с… Не знаю, почему его нет в «Русском орфографическом словаре». Скорее всего – просто упущение составителей словаря (Слава).*

4. Итак, на наших глазах рождается **"новая народная грамматика"**, тесня последователей классической науки в сторону. Не так-то просто противостоять сплоченному коллективу. (Мне, к примеру, это уже надоело, зачем тратить свои силы на то, что смысла не имеет.) Не хочешь смотреть на новые законы — здесь никто и никого не держит. Сила народного коллектива **в единстве и взаимной поддержке.** Все это ясно видно на данном примере.
5. А тем временем тема взаимоотношений **наречий и наречных предлогов** обсуждается во многих научных статьях, при этом существуют разные школы. Вот набор цитат только из одной статьи: **К вопросу о наречном управлении**. Дегальцева А.В. Дата публикации: 2019  https://www.openrepository.ru/article?id=326599

*Проведенное исследование показывает, что особенности функционирования наречий, управляющих зависимыми словоформами, отражают **активные процессы**, происходящие в современном синтаксисе.*

*В трудах представителей московской лингвистической школы, существует несколько факторов, позволяющих **установить факт** ПЕРЕХОДА какой-либо части речи (в частности, наречия) в предложную единицу.*

*В современной науке о языке существует **несколько концепций**, позволяющих охарактеризовать статус неизменяемых слов, способных управлять зависимыми именными словоформами (близко к дому, наперерез лошадям и под.)*.

*Неизменяемые слова, выражающие пространственные отношения, рассматриваются **лингвистом как наречия** даже в случае невозможности их устранения из контекста.*

*Следует отметить, что разграничение наречий и наречных предлогов бывает не всегда последовательным даже в **академических** изданиях.  И т.д.*

В статье лингвист последовательно  перечисляет **целый список факторов**, по которым определяется **переход или отсутствие** перехода наречия в наречный предлог. Так он доказывает способность к управлению для наречий образа действия. Видимо, **такой контроль** проходят все предлоги, перед тем как попасть в словарь РАН.

6. Мы видим, что в лингвистической науке данная тема решается различно **в разных школах**, но в словаре РАН обозначено **общепринятое мнение** на текущий момент. Было бы наивно полагать, что составители "забыли" внести туда предлоги, но вот-вот внесут. Но наши участники думают именно так и смело дают ответ для школьной аудитории: ***да, это предлоги.***

**Приложение** (о ссылке на "Справочник по русской грамматике")

М. А. Шелякин считает: если наречие требует определенного падежа, то оно **переходит** в наречный предлог. Это мнение **не подтверждается** в современной лингвистике. Для перехода наречия в предлог требуется наличие ряда факторов.

М. А. Шелякин (1927, Брянская обл., –  2011, Тарту, Эстония) — советский и российский лингвист, доктор филологических наук, профессор. Изучал проблемы грамматики русского языка, семиотики, общего языкознания и **преподавания русского языка как иностранного.** Из-за возрастного ценза в Тартуском университете (Эстония),  Шелякин ушёл на пенсию и стал эмеритус-профессором. Были изданы различные монографии. Одним из важнейших результатов этой работы стал "**Справочник по русской грамматике"**, представляющий собой системное описание фонетики, словообразования, морфологии, синтаксиса, орфографии и пунктуации, впервые изданный **в 1993 г**. в Москве. Адресатом "Справочника" стали **иностранцы, изучающие русский язык** и быстро оценившие его практическую направленность и удобство в использовании.

Comment: Уже сто раз заявлялось, что мнение составителей современного орфографического словаря не является аксиомой, НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ, на него можно ориентироваться только в том случае, если нам нужно проверить написание (и ссылка на словарь была уместна только в контексте темы "Причастия и прилагательные"). В остальных случаях (особенно тогда, когда речь о морфологии) нужно смотреть разные источники. А в этом вопросе орфографический словарь не помощник, т.к. отражает узость представлений специалистов, составлявших словарь.